# Convert to datetime with different types of time format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime-format

I have a dataset like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['30.09.2015', '13.10.2015 18:13:47' , '01.04.2012', '13.10.2015 18:25:36']})
```

I want to convert to time format

```
2015-09-30
2015-10-13
```

I tried to do different ways

```
pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format= '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format= '%d.%m.%Y')
pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format= c('%d.%m.%Y', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

It's wrong. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made it harder than it needed to be!  Just do this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['a'])
```

Comment: In this case I get '2015-09-30 00:00:00'. I prefer '2015-09-30'

Comment: @Edward: That's simply how Pandas prints it by default.  Pandas only has one resolution of datetime64, and that is nanoseconds, so everything is stored with those units, including the time of day.  It seems like what you're looking for now is a custom print function, which you will have to write yourself.  You can however add `.dt.date()` on the end if you want only the date for all the values.